# SQL Query Help for searching

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, search

I have 3 tables named "pictures", "pictag" and "tagging".
There is a search box in which the user types in the name of the image that they want to search. When user types in this term I want it say name, description and image.

For example, if the user "tags" an image with 'sun' then this image does not get displayed.
I have tried many things but think there might be something in my code which is stopping this. What sort of query can I use for this as the one I am trying to execute does not show an image when the "tag" is being searched for?

The query is:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT pictures.idpic, pictures.name, pictures.info, pictag.tagpicID, pictag.pictagName, tagging.IDimage, tagging.tagpicID 
    FROM pictures, pictag, tagging 
    WHERE pictures.idpic = '$searchvalueentered ' 
    AND pictag.tagpicID= '$searchvalueentered ' 
    AND tagging.tagpicID= '$searchvalueentered '";
```

Comment: try using OR instead of AND in where condition. one more thing, As per your query Input search word must match with database value. I don't think this would be preferable. Use LIKE instead of "="....

Comment: HI.. where is the relation between three tables.. look into that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are doing and what the three tables are for but have you tried to use "OR" in your where clause instead of "AND". I've got a hunch that the problem lies there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT pictures.idpic, pictures.name, pictures.info, pictag.tagpicID, pictag.pictagName, tagging.IDimage, tagging.tagpicID 
    FROM pictures, pictag, tagging 
    WHERE pictures.idpic = '" . $searchvalueentered . "' 
    OR pictag.tagpicID = '" . $searchvalueentered . "' 
    OR tagging.tagpicID = '" . $searchvalueentered . "'
";
```

You should consider using prepared statements, by the way. This is highly unsafe.

Comment: Thanks for the help Hector however, images are still not being displayed on the screen when the "tagged name" is being searched for. Do you think it could be anything to do with the whileloop as I have tweaked around with this but am getting the following error: 

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\pictures\testingsearch.php on line 45

I believe this error is due to the whileloop: 

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
}

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "
    SELECT pictures.idpic, pictures.name, pictures.info, pictag.tagpicID, pictag.pictagName, tagging.IDimage, tagging.tagpicID 
    FROM pictures, pictag, tagging
    WHERE pictures.idpic = '$searchvalueentered ' 
    OR pictag.tagpicID= '$searchvalueentered ' 
    OR tagging.tagpicID= '$searchvalueentered '";
```

Will work but you actually want to join your tables or else you will be getting duplicate records in your result (maybe this is what you want).

Assuming that pictag and tagging are 1:1 relations of your pictures table, I would urge you to try this method instead:

```
SELECT pictures.idpic, pictures.name, pictures.info, pictag.tagpicID, pictag.pictagName, tagging.IDimage, tagging.tagpicID 
FROM pictures
LEFT JOIN pictag ON pictures.idpic = pictag.tagpicID
LEFT JOIN tagging ON pictures.idpic = tagging.tagpicID
WHERE pictures.idpic = '$searchvalueentered';
```

I can't test the query for you but I suspect this will produce expected results, given that all tables are related by the "idpic" key.

Comment: It might be that the tables have no relation. In case the tables store images from different sources and what the OP wants is to search a name in any of them, then the join is not required.

Comment: @David, Thanks for the suggestion David. I have been having a go with the sql code however, the images are still not being displayed on the screen when the "tagged name" is being searched for. Do you think it could be anything to do with the 'whileloop' as I have tweaked around with this but am getting the following error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\pictures\testingsearch.php on line 45 I believe this error is due to the whileloop: $result = mysql_query($sql); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ }

Comment: Ah well I do know quite a bit about PHP.  I like to work with PEAR MDB2 or Laravel but not too often with the native methods.  You might check your query or add some error handling to your logic.  For instance - `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ - etc.`.  mysql_query returns false on error.

Comment: My last comment may not be obvious but if `$result` is boolean false, then `mysql_fetch_array` will bomb.  Also, if you haven't tried it yet, check out MySQL Query Browser or MySQL Workbench to debug your queries.  It's a good addition to your workflow while you're developing.

Answer (score 0):

As David mentioned, you should try joining your tables to eliminate duplicates and to simplify the search, you can try..

```
SELECT 
    pictures.idpic, 
    pictures.name, 
    pictures.info, 
    pictag.tagpicID, 
    pictag.pictagName, 
    tagging.IDimage, 
    tagging.tagpicID 
FROM pictures
INNER JOIN pictag 
    ON pictures.idpic = pictag.tagpicID
INNER JOIN tagging 
    ON pictures.idpic = tagging.tagpicID
WHERE 
    CONCAT_WS(' ',pictures.idpic,pictag.tagpicID,tagging.tagpicID) LIKE %$searchvalueentered%
```

Note: not a very optimised solution.